# Speed up pandas read_csv for large csv with variable rows and 50K+ columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to read in a CSV file containing variable number of columns and row in order to compute (Min,Max,Mean,75/95 quantile) values of each column. The number of columns is very large (More than 10K columns , can go upto 100K columns or more depending on experiment configuration).Typical number of rows can be 3000 samples. Typical CSV is 700MB in size.

What I know about the dataset:

1. The first column is a date type
2. Position and name of other columns differ from data-set to data-set and are unknown at
   the time of loading the data.
3. The data in all columns except the first column is either of type int64 or float64.
4. I can apply some heuristics to predetermine the datatype of some but not all columns from their names.

My main bottleneck for doing the analysis is loading the dataset using pandas `read_csv`. Once the dataset has been loaded into the dataframe rest of the computation is very fast.

If I were computing only min, max & average I could have read the dataset in chunks and tried to speed up the `read_csv` part. However in order to determine the different quantiles, I believe the entire column must be read into the dataframe.

How can I speed up the data loading phase

1. Can I specify some but not all the columns in the dtype argument
   to `read_csv`. Does this contribute to speedup of reading the csv. If
   so why?

I found out that it does indeed contribute to speed up. Looks like Pandas spends considerable time deciding the datatype. I created the dtype dictionary using some heuristics on the column name. By providing the dtype argument in readCSV the number of function calls to determine type went down leading to a slight speed up. This is also evident from the profile .

Profile before optimizing 
[image: Top function calls in unoptimized read_csv]

Profile after optimizing
[image: Top function calls after providing the dtype argument for most columns]

2. Is there any other optimizations based on what I know about the
   data that I can use to load faster?

Comment: I suggest you should try to process the data using the data-parallel processing technique (ex: pyspark).

Comment: Maybe you could look at https://github.com/vaexio/vaex

Comment: Consider checking out the [dask library[(https://dask.org/)

Comment: @MartijntenHoor: Do I need to convert the csv to some other format before loading the data using vaex? vaex.from_csv was just as slow in reading the csv out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the patience to load the data once, then you can save it in another format, as `parquet` or `feather`, which will be faster to re-upload later.

Another option to check out is the [dask](https://dask.org/) library.

Comment: Hi, I don't need to load the data again and again. I generate a report from the data once loaded and that is the only time I load the data